# PHP: Splitting by ", " and show

Tags: php

```
$number = 1;
$number2 = "2, 3, 4";
     $searchstatus = array(" - ", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4");
```

I have this array.

$number2 is like how its stored in the database.

How can i split them up by `", "` if theres more than 1(like $number) and make a echo ouput that says:

`f2 and then f3 and then f4`

(values to 2, 3, 4)

So if its $number just echo "f1" , if theres more than 1 "entry" like $number2, echo like above^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, please clarify.

In the meantime, I think you are looking for [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

---

Use something like:

```
$searchstatus = array(" - ", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4");
$arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', '1,2,3'));
foreach ($arr as $key) {
    echo $searchstatus[$key] . " ";
}
```

Prints:

```
f1 f2 f3
```

Comment: How can I connect this with my array, so it displays f1, f2, f3 than 1, 2, 3

Comment: @user What do you mean by "connect"? How are elements in both arrays associated? By index? By content?

Comment: $searchstatus = array(" - ", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4");
$arr = explode(',', '1,2,3');   I have this, now I would like to echo the array content out, something like(i know this isnt right) echo $searchstatus[$arr]. so the exploded 1 2 3 would echo out f1 f2 f3

Answer (score 0):

If the spacing around your commas is inconsistent, you'll want to use preg_split():

```
$list = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you have a string Like this

```
$str='1,2,3.......n';
```

Use PHP explode function that is as

```
$exp=explode(','$str);
```

It will split the string into any array of pieces like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [n] => 3
)
```

If you want convert the array to string then use PHP `implode()`

```
implode(',',$arr);
```

For white spaces removal from left and right of the values then use `trim()`.